# How to convert columns into an array using Big Query

Tags: arrays, google-bigquery

Basically I have 3 String columsn, A, B and C. All of them could have NULL values.

I have tried:

```
select 
  [A,B,C] as tags 
from table
```

if A have a NULL value the output should be ["B_VALUE", "C_VALUE"].

If B have NULL value, the oputput should be ["A_VALUE", "C_VALUE"].

And so on.

I am getting `Array cannot have a null element; error in writing field tags`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider below approach (BigQuery Standard SQL)

```
select id, 
  ( select array_agg(trim(col) order by offset)
    from unnest(split(regexp_replace(format('%t', (A,B,C)),r'^\(|\)$',''))) col with offset
    where not trim(col) = 'NULL'
  ) as tags
from your_table
```

if apply to dummy data as below

```
with your_table as (
  select 1 id, 'a' A, 'b' B, 'c' C union all
  select 2, null, 'bb', 'cc' union all
  select 3, 'aaa', null, 'ccc'
)    
select id, 
  ( select array_agg(trim(col) order by offset)
    from unnest(split(regexp_replace(format('%t', (A,B,C)),r'^\(|\)$',''))) col with offset
    where not trim(col) = 'NULL'
  ) as tags
from your_table
```

the output is

[image]

Or even simpler

```
select id,
  ( select array_agg(col order by offset)
    from unnest([A,B,C]) col with offset
    where not col is null
  ) as tags
from your_table
```

with the same result